# In the Doctor Who episode "Blink", why do the angel statues appear in weird places?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-who

There are two specific scenes I'm thinking of where angel statues inexplicably appear in strange places.

The first is when Sally Sparrow is in the police depot and looks out the window and sees angel statues on the church across the street.  When she looks again, they are gone.

You can view this scene here:

The second scene is when the officer is in the basement with all the cars.  Sally leaves, and when he turns around, the room is full of angel statues.

You can view this scene here:

Can anybody explain these two scenes within the rules imposed by the episode?

Comment: Why exactly do you think those scenes should be impossible?

Comment: How do they appear and disappear so quickly?  I know they're supposed to be fast, but in the house the angels aren't THAT speedy.  I mean one second the officer sees a bunch of cars, the next he's surrounded by angels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The angels had followed Sparrow to the police station, and they generally hide themselves in positions where you'd expect to see statues (like the church across the street). But when Sparrow turned her back they went across the road into the police station. Once they got to the carpark there was no need to hide any more so they showed themselves more openly.

Why do they seem to move so slowly in the house compared to out in public? I think the main reason is because it made for suspenseful TV. If you like though, imagine something like "the angels move faster when there are more people *not* looking at them."

Comment: They can only move when no living thing can see them, though. How likely is it that no people or animals (squirrels, rats, birds, etc.) at all could see them crossing the street? Yes, they're fast, but Andrew's comment on the question is right: They don't move that quickly in the house.

Comment: Added two possible "explanations" for why they're so slow in the house.

Comment: @dgw: Maybe they're slow in the house specifically because they get observed by little creatures constantly (thus flickering in and out of their petrified state, moving as if they have a bad framerate).

Comment: Going by the "quantum-locked" explanation, they should also freeze when anything can hear them. That would explain why they move slowly when stalking someone in a house.